# Multiple Alias, one Column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, alias, psql

I am trying to give multiple Aliases to the same column, basically, i want these two queries to be one:

```
SELECT name AS singlePeople FROM People
JOIN ID FROM Numbers
ON People.ID=Numbers.ID
WHERE People.isMarried=f;


SELECT name AS marriedPeople FROM People
JOIN ID FROM Numbers
ON People.ID=Numbers.ID
WHERE People.isMarried=t;
```

I want my results to look like:

```
singlePeople    marriedPeople
-------------   --------------
Bob Kelly        John SMith
John Adams
```

Comment: What do the tables look like?  It is not obvious to me why you need a `join`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this sufficient?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p.isMarried THEN 'Married' ELSE 'Single' END) as which,
       name
FROM People p JOIN 
     Numbers n
     ON p.ID = n.ID;
```

If not, you can do this with variables:

```
select max(case when not ismarried then name end) as single,
       max(case when ismarried then name end) as married
from (select name, p.ismarried,
             (@rn := if(@i = ismarried, @rn + 1,
                        if(@i := ismarried, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from people p join
           numbers n
           on p.id = n.id cross join
           (select @i := NULL, @rn := 0) params
      order by ismarried
     ) pn
group by rn;
```